# shouldInterceptRequest opening link in browser

Tags: android, android-webview

In my application, I have a webview that shows an image. I would like to intercept the click on the image and open URL pointed by image's *href* attribute in a browser. 
I am using *shouldInterceptRequest* method from WebViewClient, but I am not sure what to return as a response from that method.
What I would like to do looks something like:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
            final Intent browserIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivityForResult(browserIntent);
            return null;     
}
```

What is the correct way to implement this?
What should my WebResourceResponse object contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to intercept the href click, you should use this shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

shouldInterceptRequest is called each time a resource is loaded like a css file, a js file etc...
shouldOverrideUrlLoading is called when a new page is about to be opened

Here is what you want to do :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivityForResult(i);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldOverrideUrlLoading merely returns true, while the actual overriding happens in 'onLoadResource' method, which is again called every time a resource (css file, js file) is loaded.

Comment: if your implementation of ShouldOverrideUrlLoading returns true, then you have to manage yourself the action. If you return false, the new page will open in your webview.